# Confidence Intervals for a Large Sample

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

> The following $95\%$ confidence interval was constructed using a large sample of data: $(86.52,89.48)$. Which of the following could be a $99\%$ confidence interval for the same set of data?
>
> $I. (86.98,89.02)$
>
> $II. (86.37,89.63)$
>
> $III. (87.04,88.98)$

My attempt: It is a large sample of data so we can approximate the sampling distribution with a Normal model. The mean is $$\bar{x} = \frac{86.52+89.48}{2}=88$$
The margin of error for the $95\%$ confidence interval is $$z^*\cdot (\text{Standard Error}) = 1.96(SE) = (89.48-88) = 1.48$$
This gives us that $SE$ is $.755$. The critical $z$ value for a $99\%$ interval is about $2.58$. The new margin of error is now $.755\cdot2.58 = 1.95$ So the $99\%$ confidence interval is now $(88-1.95,88+1.95) = (86.05,89.95)$. Which is not one of the answers. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The question only says "could be", not "is", maybe you were not expected to do any calculations.

Answer (score 1):

A higher confidence level will merely widen the interval. This leaves choice $II.$

Comment: Yes but why does my method not give the exact answer?

Comment: @JamesCooper I feel that the question was designed to be more theoretical, rather than computational.

Comment: @james because you have no idea what is the distribution of the underlying parameter. Remember, most thing in life aren't normal.

Answer (score 0):

It is the *mean* of any distribution that is asymptotically normal. Your 'large sample of data' isn't necessarily normal -- it could follow any distribution. Since a wider CI is always wider, it must be II.